# Having trouble in converting data into NSString from NSData

Tags: nsstring, nsdata, ios5.1

I want to convert NSData into NSString, my code is below.

```
NSData *data1 = [object valueForKey:@"college_list"];
NSString *myString =[ NSString stringWithCString:[data1 bytes] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: 'data1' have some value in it? What is is the output of 'myString'?

Comment: Is data really a `NSData` object or a `NSString` object (with "data hex representation)? Are your sure about the encoding?

Comment: in 'data1' it is showing 1091 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If 'data1' do have some thing in it. Try this:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

May be there is some this wrong with your 'object'. Check its data is valid or issue is in its data.

Comment: thanks Waleem Mahmood but this is not working. 'myString' still showing nil.  'data1' having 1091 bytes. i think there is no issue with 'data1'.

Comment: Is your data encrypted in 'data1'?

Comment: Ok iam telling you the whole process briefly than you can understand better.   Iam creating an array of NSstring and storing into core data in bytes format after converting it into NSData . Now iam fetching it from coredata and obvious data will come in NSData format. so i want to convert it into NSString. Data is not in encrypted form.